# Combine p::first-letter and before

Tags: css

I tried all ways to make the check tick before each p but it's not working.

Only the first-letter works.

Any ideas ?

```
.text_intro {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 720px;
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.text_intro p::first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2DB243;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.text_intro p::first-letter::before {
    content: "✔";
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I haven't got the time to check the spec, but I'm pretty sure that a pseudo-element – the `::first-letter` – can't itself contain another pseudo-element – the `::before`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info).  Instead of telling us what you are trying to do, instead tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: is this(https://jsfiddle.net/LostInCode404/13qqu2pm/2/) what you are trying to accomplish? If yes, I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the snippet below.

Change `.text_intro p::first-letter::before` to `.text_intro p::before` and set `position: absolute;` for the tick and `padding-left: 25px` so that the content of `p` tag wrap automatically if it comes to the next line.

```css
.text_intro p::first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2DB243;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.text_intro p::before {
    content: "✔";
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:2px;
}

.text_intro p{
    position:relative;
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_intro">
  <p>Curabitur vestibulum sem sed justo commodo, sit amet porttitor urna interdum.
</p>
<p>Vivamus euismod tellus et tortor mattis, id pharetra erat varius.
</p>
<p>Maecenas molestie lorem ac tellus pharetra, ac consectetur nisi tristique.
</p>
</div>
```